# Node and Express can't find my js folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder structure for my Node.JS app

```
 /
 |-js
    |-ajax.js
 |-img
 |-css
 |-views
    |-index.html
 |-router
    |-main.js
 |-node_modules
 |-server.js
```

My server.js file looks like

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
require('./router/main')(app);
app.set('views',__dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
var server=app.listen(3000,function() {
  console.log("Express is running on port 3000");
});
```

I am very new to Node and Express. When I try to include a js file within my index.html (inside views), it says the file can't be found. I don't understand why

```
../js/ajax.js
```

is unable to be found from my index.html

I think the same issue is happening with my css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your js directory as static.

```
app.use(express.static('js'));
```

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

However I would recommend doing this with your directory structure:

```
-static
  -js
    -ajax.js
  -img
  -css
-views
-router
```

And then

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

Comment: I just tried that and it can't find the js file. Can you please elaborate a little. Do I need to make any changes to the HTML? You did not mention that I need to download the path library so I did that with npm install path --save nor did your response indicate that I needed to use "var path = require('path');".

Comment: it would be `../ajax.js'`

Comment: Or `../js/ajax.js` if you do the static structure like I recommended.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.. You don't actually need to use `path.join(__dirname` I updated the answer..

Comment: Ok I will do as you advise about moving my js, img and css folders within static. But whats the reason?

Comment: The reason is really just so you can keep all static content in one location. Technically you could leave them as is. However you would then need to define each directory as static. For example.. `app.use(express.static('js')); app.use(express.static('img')); app.use(express.static('css'));`